# postgres select where from rows generated by regexp_split_to_table with union throws error

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'my_table' with two columns(c1,c2) holding data in the exact same format '1,2,3,4;5,6,7,8'
I use regexp_split_to_table to split them into rows, and I'm trying to select non-empty rows.

```
SELECT * from 
 (SELECT '1' as param1 ,'2' as param2, param3 FROM
  ((select regexp_split_to_table(my_table.c1, ';') as param3
   FROM  my_table)
 UNION
  (select regexp_split_to_table(my_table.c2, ';') as param3
   FROM  my_table)) AS a) as b

 where param3 is not null
```

running this query gives the following error:

```
set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set
```

if I remove the union and select only from one of the columns, or filter by one of the other fields (param1/param2), the query works.
I thought it might be an issue with the data so I tried selecting from the same column twice:

```
SELECT * from 
 (SELECT '1' as param1 ,'2' as param2, param3 FROM
  ((select regexp_split_to_table(my_table.c1, ';') as param3
   FROM  my_table)
 UNION
  (select regexp_split_to_table(my_table.c1, ';') as param3
   FROM  my_table)) AS a) as b

 where param3 is not null
```

but I still get the same error.
does anybody know how to solve this?
thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using CTE instead of subqueries and format your queries. Here's the query I think you need:

```
with cte1 as (
  select regexp_split_to_table(t.c1, ';') as param3
  from my_table as t
  union all
  select regexp_split_to_table(t.c2, ';') as param3
  from my_table as t
)
select '1' as param1 ,'2' as param2, c.param3
from cte1 as c
where c.param3 is not null
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d7b07/2)

note: I don't know if you need duplicates or not in your query, so if you don't need it - use `union` instead of `union all`

**update**

```
with cte1 as (
  select regexp_split_to_table(t.c1, ';') as param3
  from my_table as t
  union all
  select regexp_split_to_table(t.c2, ';') as param3
  from my_table as t
), cte2 as (
  select regexp_split_to_table(c.param3, ',') as param3
  from cte1 as c
  where c.param3 is not null and c.param3 <> ''
)
select *
from cte2 as c
where c.param3 is not null and c.param3 <> ''
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d62e9/5)

**update2** it could be even done with one regexp

```
with cte1 as (
    select c1 as param3 from my_table
    union all
    select c2 as param3 from my_table
), cte2 as (
  select regexp_split_to_table(param3, '(;|,)') as param3
  from cte1
)
select '1' as param1 ,'2' as param2, c.param3
from cte2 as c
where nullif(c.param3, '') <> ''
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d62e9/9)

Comment: thanks! this solves the problem I had. when using subquery I can name it 'as dt(a)' for further splitting of the data. is it possible with cte?

Comment: simple and perfect. dunno why I didn't think of it myself... thanks

Comment: @avital added version with one regex